# find a view using tag in a gridview using databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am trying to convert the usual use of findViewById to a databinding. It seems pretty straight forward but the complexity is that the view is inside a GridLayout and each view inside has been tagged so I can find them. The current code is :

```
        val layout: GridLayout =
            binding.quickCommandGridLayout

        val view: CardView = layout.findViewWithTag(name.toString())
        val tileLayout: CardView = view.findViewById(R.id.tileLayout)
```

So I am using the `name` to get the proper `CardView` I am looking for and then be able to access the element inside this `CardView` it's working fine the way it is but almost the entire app is using databinding so I would like consistency in the app transform my `findViewById` to databinding instead.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: You need to add id to the Views inside `GridLayout`. Since you are using a `ViewGroup` i suppose there aren't too many child of `GridLayout` so just add an id to each this is only way i guess. If you have too many views inside `GridLayout` then u are probably using it wrong, u should be using `RecyclerView`  in this case .

Comment: @ADM each view are added programmatically. that's why I am using tag